# Java: Can i use a boolean with a input in java

Tags: java

am new to learning java and I have set myself a task of creating a shopping basket.

Here is my code:

```
System.out.println("Grapes " + "£" + grapes + "    Quantity:");
    input= amount.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You Selected " + input + " Grapes");
```

How can i add a boolean so when someone says they want to order 1 bunch of grapes it comes up with "Bunch of Grapes", and when someone orders 2+ bunches of grapes it comes up with "Bunches of grapes" .

Thank you for you help,

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do something like:

```
boolean multiple_grapes = (Integer.valueOf(input) > 1);
if (multiple_grapes) {
  System.out.println("You Selected " + input + " Bunches of Grapes");
} else {
  System.out.println("You Selected " + input + " Bunch of Grapes");
}
```

You need to parse `input` to `Integer` in order to be able to compare it with the integer value `1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(input);
if(num == 1){
    // do whatever you want
}
else {
    // another action
}
```

Actually, you can even compare string representation without parsing

```
if(input.equals("1"))
```

but I guess you will need integer representation anyway